# How to display and update a "sub-page" within a condition (using primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a scenario to achieve but I don't know how to do it(I'am using primefaces)
The scenario is:
I have a selectOneMenu that contain options that the user can choose one of them,
when the user choose an option ,a "form" or a "Sub-page" should appear below the selectOneMenu , the user should fill it.
The  "Sub-page" change according to the choosen option

eg :option1 ---> Sub-Page1

option2 --->Sub-Page2    etc..

JSF

```
<h:selectOneMenu  style="width:200px" immediate="true"  value="#{ToolsKPI.myChoice}" onchange="submit()"  valueChangeListener="#{BeanTest.selectChangeHandler}" required="true" >
           <f:selectItems value="#{ToolsKPI.getMyListKPI()}" />
             </h:selectOneMenu>

         <p:panel rendered="#{BeanTest.showPanelBool}" >
          <h1>KPI1</h1>
           <br></br>
             <h:inputText value="test1" />
         </p:panel>
                <p:panel rendered="#{BeanTest.showPanelBool1}" >
                    <br></br>
                    <h1>KPI2</h1>
              <h:inputText value="test2" />
             <h:inputText value="test3" />
         </p:panel>
```

**My Bean**

```
public class BeanTest implements java.io.Serializable {

 private String myChoice;
 private  boolean showPanelBool;
private  boolean showPanelBool1;


  public BeanTest() {
}

//getters ande setters


public void selectChangeHandler(ValueChangeEvent event){

 myChoice = (String) event.getNewValue(); // Must however be the exact page URL. E.g. "contact.jsf".
  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

if(myChoice.equals("Number Of Closed issues") ){
this.showPanelBool = true;
} else{
this.showPanelBool = false;
this.showPanelBool1 = true;
}  
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
}

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really post some semblance of the code: a picture something. What you're probably looking for is a "p:outputPanel" component or something similar.

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/outputPanel.jsf

You can do something with a ValueChangeListener akin to

```
public void onSelectItem(ValueChangeEvent evt)
{
  if("someValue".equals(evt.getNewValue())
    showPageOne = true;//boolean
  else
    showPageTwo = true;//boolean
}

//JSF
<h:form id="myForm">
  <h:selectOneMenu valueChangeListener="#{myBean.onSelectItem}" update="myForm">
    <f:selectItems value="items">
  </h:selectOneMenu>
  <p:outputPanel rendered="#{myBean.showPageOne}">
    hi I'm page one
  </p:outputPanel>

  <p:outputPanel rendered="#{myBean.showPageTwo}">
    hi I'm page two
  </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

Sorry for the pseudo code, the examples on Primefaces will really help you here. OutputPanel has saved my bacon often. You'll need to specify an update target, but the example is really clear and easy to run. Play with it.

*(Also Primefaces is fantastic you'll likely be very happy with their component suite)*

Comment: Hello ,thank you for the reply ;I have tried to add a GUI sketch but I can't beacause I don't have the right, I'am new here and I haven't add a code beacause I dont know how can I do it :( ,this why I couldn't be clear also my english is not so good :) .      So I have read your answer but it's not what I want as result ,I want a form (will be fill by the user and it change according the choice ) that at first dont exist then when the user choose an option the form will appear below the Combobox(SelectOneMenu).

Comment: hello I have solved my problem ,I have updated the post I hope it will help sombody else :)